# Duplicate Content-Length with Axios running in NodeJS/JEST

Tags: jestjs, axios, nanoexpress

I face really weird problem with Axios / nanoexpress.  I started to write JEST test and copied working piece of code from Vuex that calls my backend. This code works reliably in Vue but here it fails with a network error. The Axios version is the same on both SPA and JEST test.

JEST:

```
let response = await axios.get(`${API}/users/1234`, getAuthHeader()); 

function getAuthHeader() {
    const config = { headers: { } };
    config.headers.Authorization = "bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOiIxZTQwdjBiMWo1Iiwibmlja25hbWUiOiJsaXRlcmFrbCIsInB3ZFRpbWVzdGFtcCI6IjIwMjAtMDMtMjJUMTE6MTA6NDkuNDg2WiIsInJvbGVzIjpbImFkbWluOnBvbGwiXSwiaWF0IjoxNTg2NjkwNzc2LCJleHAiOjE1ODkzNjkxNzZ9.N5MfpZ9i9Sjv-izdYItR4gXCmzVkqkuVcVSEL_6Q89c";
    return config;
}
```

When I remove the config with Authorization header, the code works well:

```
let response = await axios.get(`${API}/users/1234`, getAuthHeader());
```

This is the error:

```
Network Error

  at createError (node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
  at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:83:14)
  at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/create-event-accessor.js:33:32)
  at innerInvokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:316:27)
  at invokeEventListeners (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:267:3)
  at XMLHttpRequestEventTargetImpl._dispatch (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/events/EventTarget-impl.js:214:9)
  at fireAnEvent (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/events.js:17:36)
  at requestErrorSteps (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:121:3)
  at Object.dispatchError (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:51:3)
  at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:675:20)
  at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:384:47)
  at Request.onRequestError (node_modules/request/request.js:877:8)

console.error node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/virtual-console.js:29
Error: Error: Parse Error: Duplicate Content-Length
    at Object.dispatchError (C:\Users\leos\WebstormProjects\nano-options\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr-utils.js:54:19)
    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\leos\WebstormProjects\nano-options\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xmlhttprequest.js:675:20)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:327:22)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\leos\WebstormProjects\nano-options\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\xhr-utils.js:384:47)
    at Request.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\leos\WebstormProjects\nano-options\node_modules\request\request.js:877:8)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:486:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12) undefined
```

The service is nothing fancy and it is never called when Authorization header is present and it is called when the Authorization header is missing.

```
app.get('/v1/users/:userId', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("getUser handler starts");
    const response = {};
    res.send(response);
    return res;
});
```

I have spent several hours trying to see the raw network communication but failed. It must be something with Axios because I can run successfuly exactly the same request with the Authorization header from Postman.

Update:

it seems to be related to NodeJS version. I submitted an issue: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2889

Update 2:

I switched from Axios to Got and the test is working properly. https://github.com/literakl/mezinamiridici/commit/e667c5661429fc8cba273716dfced2244e211abf

Comment: Here is the minimum reproducible repository: https://github.com/literakl/nano-options/blob/master/api.int.test.js

Comment: what node version is required? tried to run it locally but got " This version of µWS is not compatible with your Node.js build: Error: Cannot find module './uws_win32_x64_57.node' from 'uws.js'"

Comment: it is Node 13.11.

Comment: just for your information: what someone flags post they never get notifications on comments, answers etc. So whoever flagged it, may see you asking for reason only by accident

Comment: I've installed NodeJS v12.16.2 and got "  ● user accounts › create user
    expect(received).toBeTruthy()
    Received: undefined
" instead of error because of duplicated "Content-Length"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211486/discussion-between-skyboyer-and-leos-literak).